# Is it possible to make a "search and replace" work where the replacement is a variable containing `$1`, `$2`, ... special variables?

Tags: perl, replace, capture-group

Is it possible to make a "search and replace" work where the replacement is a variable containing `$1`, `$2`, ... special variables?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.0;

my $row = 'ab';
my $pattern = '^(.)(.)';
my $replacement = '$2-$1';
$row =~ s/$pattern/$replacement/;
say $row; # $2-$1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [String::Substitution](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Substitution)'s `sub_modify`.

```perl
use String::Substitution qw( sub_modify );

sub_modify( $row, $pattern, $replacement );
```

Notes:

- Use `gsub` instead of `sub` if you want the behaviour of the `g` modifier.
- Use `copy` instead of `modify` if you want the behaviour of the `r` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

"When all you have is a nail everything looks like a hammer."

If internal politics (corporate policy) inhibits the convenient installation of modules:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.0;

my $row = 'ab';
my $pattern = '^(.)(.)';
#my $replacement= '$2-$1';
my $replacement;
#$row =~ s/$pattern/$replacement/;
$row =~ s/$pattern(?{$replacement="$2-$1"})/$replacement/e;
say $row; # b-a
```

Perhaps this do?

Comment: Re "*Perhaps this do?*", No. This hardcodes `$2-$1`, so this is just a horrible way to write `s/$pattern/$2-$1/`. And that's obviously not what the OP wants.